# Op type not registered 'BatchDatasetV2'

Tags: google-cloud-tpu

I’m trying to train a model and am using tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder to prepare my dataset. When I run estimator.train I get the following error:

> NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'BatchDatasetV2' in binary
>   running on n-be8b2535-w-0. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered
>   in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a
>   saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.)
>   `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as
>   contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.

I’m not trying to run from a saved graph and I’ve made sure that I’m using a fresh model_dir. How do I fix this? This only happens when I run on TPU. Running on CPU works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can arise if you have different versions of tensorflow on your VM and on the TPU. Check the version on your VM by running:

```
    import tensorflow
    print tensorflow.__version__
```

Check the version on your TPU by going to the TPU page on the GCP console:
https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/tpus

Set the version of tensorflow on your VM via pip. So if you want to set your VM tensorflow version to 1.9, run:

```
    pip install tensorflow==1.9
```

Comment: you will probably have to do `pip uninstall tensorflow` first, if going to an older version