# Tensorflow TPU Training: NotFoundError ParallelInterleaveDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to train a neural network using a TPU on Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

I have saved my files as tfrecords locally and opened a Jupyter Notebook running on a virtual machine (compute engine) where I am writing my code for training.

My code executes until it starts training. I then get the error message:

> NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'ParallelInterleaveDataset' in
>   binary running on n-b2696fa0-w-0. Make sure the Op and Kernel are
>   registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are
>   loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.)
>   `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as
>   contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.

I did some googling and come across this by google: [unavailable tensorflow op](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting#unavailable_tensorflow_op). It states that some operations are not permissible in code for TPUs.

However, I never use a function called "ParallelInterleaveDataset". My question is: 
**What might be the reason for this problem and what can I do to solve it and train my network on the TPU?**

--

**The entire error message for the sake of completeness:**

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:TPU job name tpu_worker
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Error recorded from training_loop: Op type not registered 'ParallelInterleaveDataset' in binary running on n-b2696fa0-w-0. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
INFO:tensorflow:training_loop marked as finished
WARNING:tensorflow:Reraising captured error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
-> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1316       # Ensure any changes to the graph are reflected in the runtime.
-> 1317       self._extend_graph()
   1318       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _extend_graph(self)
   1351     with self._graph._session_run_lock():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1352       tf_session.ExtendSession(self._session)
   1353 

NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'ParallelInterleaveDataset' in binary running on n-b2696fa0-w-0. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-ee69fe04790e> in <module>
----> 1 tpu_estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1)

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
   2407       if ctx.is_running_on_cpu(is_export_mode=False):
   2408         with ops.device('/device:CPU:0'):
-> 2409           return input_fn(**kwargs)
   2410 
   2411       # For TPU computation, input_fn should be invoked in a tf.while_loop for

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/error_handling.py in raise_errors(self, timeout_sec)
    126       else:
    127         logging.warn('Reraising captured error')
--> 128         six.reraise(typ, value, traceback)
    129 
    130     for k, (typ, value, traceback) in kept_errors:

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
   2401       if batch_size_for_input_fn is not None:
   2402         _add_item_to_params(kwargs['params'], _BATCH_SIZE_KEY,
-> 2403                             batch_size_for_input_fn)
   2404 
   2405       # For export_savedmodel, input_fn is never passed to Estimator. So,

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_with_estimator_spec(self, estimator_spec, worker_hooks, hooks, global_step_tensor, saving_listeners)

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in MonitoredTrainingSession(master, is_chief, checkpoint_dir, scaffold, hooks, chief_only_hooks, save_checkpoint_secs, save_summaries_steps, save_summaries_secs, config, stop_grace_period_secs, log_step_count_steps, max_wait_secs, save_checkpoint_steps, summary_dir)
    502 
    503   if hooks:
--> 504     all_hooks.extend(hooks)
    505   return MonitoredSession(
    506       session_creator=session_creator,

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in __init__(self, session_creator, hooks, stop_grace_period_secs)
    919   * it cannot be sent to tf.train.start_queue_runners.
    920 
--> 921   Args:
    922     session_creator: A factory object to create session. Typically a
    923       `ChiefSessionCreator` which is the default one.

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in __init__(self, session_creator, hooks, should_recover, stop_grace_period_secs)
    641 
    642     # Create the session.
--> 643     self._coordinated_creator = self._CoordinatedSessionCreator(
    644         session_creator=session_creator or ChiefSessionCreator(),
    645         hooks=self._hooks,

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in __init__(self, sess_creator)
   1105 
   1106   Calls to `run()` are delegated to the wrapped session.  If a call raises the
-> 1107   exception `tf.errors.AbortedError` or `tf.errors.UnavailableError`, the
   1108   wrapped session is closed, and a new one is created by calling the factory
   1109   again.

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in _create_session(self)
   1110   """
   1111 
-> 1112   def __init__(self, sess_creator):
   1113     """Create a new `_RecoverableSession`.
   1114 

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in create_session(self)
    798       self.coord = None
    799       self.tf_sess = None
--> 800       self._stop_grace_period_secs = stop_grace_period_secs
    801 
    802     def create_session(self):

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in create_session(self)
    564         self._master,
    565         saver=self._scaffold.saver,
--> 566         checkpoint_dir=self._checkpoint_dir,
    567         checkpoint_filename_with_path=self._checkpoint_filename_with_path,
    568         config=self._config,

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py in prepare_session(self, master, init_op, saver, checkpoint_dir, checkpoint_filename_with_path, wait_for_checkpoint, max_wait_secs, config, init_feed_dict, init_fn)
    292     if not local_init_success:
    293       raise RuntimeError(
--> 294           "Init operations did not make model ready for local_init.  "
    295           "Init op: %s, init fn: %s, error: %s" % (_maybe_name(init_op),
    296                                                    init_fn,

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    927     try:
    928       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 929                          run_metadata_ptr)
    930       if run_metadata:
    931         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1150     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1151       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1152                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1153     else:
   1154       results = []

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1326     if handle is None:
   1327       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1328                            run_metadata)
   1329     else:
   1330       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

~/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1346           pass
   1347       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1348       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1349 
   1350   def _extend_graph(self):

NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'ParallelInterleaveDataset' in binary running on n-b2696fa0-w-0. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, this happened because I was using two different versions of Tensorflow. So the solution is to specify the version of Tensorflow version on startup. I used the `ctpu` tool as so:

`ctpu up --tpu-size=[TPU_VERSION] --tf-version=[TF VERSION]`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903149/op-type-not-registered-batchdatasetv2)